# Equivalence class of polynomials in abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Suppose I have the set of polynomials $P$ in one real variable.

$p(t) = t^3 + 2t^2 + 3t + 5, p ∈ P$.

And I have an equivalence relation $\sim$ on P defined as $a \sim b$ if $a = b + pq$ for some $q \in P$.

How can I show that each equivalence class has a unique representative of a degree less than $3$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_greatest_common_divisor#Euclidean_division

Comment: $f\bmod p$ is the unique rep of $f$ of degree $<  3,\,$ by the (Euclidean) Polynomial Division Algorithm - see the dupe.

Comment: @Locallyunskillful thanks that really helped

Comment: @Gone Thanks for your answer. The comment from wiki above and yours helped me

Comment: @StevenHarrigan Great! If you need further details please feel welcome to ask there. We have many answers that explain these and related ideas.